# How to use 'patch' command with the standard output?

Tags: linux, bash, patch

I'm trying to catch an output of bash `patch` on stdout, but I receive an error:

```bash
patch -o- some/file 
patch: can't output patches to standard output
```

Can I get the patch result on stdout?

Comment: what do you want the patch *output* for?

Comment: I'm writing some kind of CVS and need to restore file condition on the time specified. So, I need to patch a 'keyframe' file with a last 'diff'-file exist on that time, that's because of rules of incremental backup.

Comment: Bash doesn't have a patch command.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. Use a temporary file to collect the patched file, cat the temp file and then delete it. A one-liner would be:

   ```
   patch fileToPatch patch.diff -o temp.out;cat temp.out;rm temp.out
   ```
2. Send the output directly to `/dev/tty`:

   ```
   patch fileToPatch patch.diff -o /dev/tty
   ```

Comment: Given how clean `-o /dev/tty` looks and seems to be, is there a reason you'd use the multi-command temp-file approach? Is `/dev/tty` inaccessible in some cases?

Comment: If you want to pipe the output of patch , instead of using `/dev/tty`, use `/dev/stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "-o -" to explicitly redirect the output to stdout:

patch fileToPatch patch.diff -o -

Hope it helps

Comment: The poster already tried that. It gives `patch: **** can't output patches to standard output` error